# Java list items re-added to thymeleaf dropdown on page reload, appearing multiple times

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, html-select

I am building a Spring Boot app that calculates and displays Airbnb payouts on a monthly basis. Payout data is pulled in from the Airbnb Api, and user account information is stored in a database. 
I have created a form where the user can specify the month and the listing to display the monthly payout. The user chooses the listing (the rental) from a dropdown menu. To display the names of the listings, a listingListDto attribute is added to the MVC model. A List of Listing entities is obtained from the database, and it is converted to a List of ListingDTO entities. This list gives the listingListDto.

When I reload the form page, the listings are readded to the dropdown, appearing twice, then three, four and more times.

How could I prevent this from happening? 
I assume I could create a ListingListDTO entity, which would wrap the List of ListingDTOs, but I was hoping to be able to keep things simple, and use the List of ListingDTOs directly in the MVC model.

Here is the Controller method that displays the html form :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "payout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String payoutSelection(Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        Long userId = sessionService.getCurrentUserId();
        if (null == userId) {
            return loginService.handleInvalidLogin("payout", redirectAttributes);
        } else {
            PayoutSelectionDTO payoutSelectionDto = new PayoutSelectionDTO();
            LocalDate lastMonth = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1);
            payoutSelectionDto.setYear(lastMonth.getYear());
            payoutSelectionDto.setMonth(lastMonth.getMonthValue());

            Optional<User> user = userService.getUserById(userId);
            model.addAttribute("payoutSelectionDto", payoutSelectionDto);
            model.addAttribute("listingListDto", listingListDtoService.getListingListDTO(listingService.getListingsByUser(user.get())));
            return "payout_monthpicker.html";
        }
    }
```

Here is the form which contains the dropdown of listings:

```html
<body>
    <div class="content-block">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/get_payouts}"
            th:object="${payoutSelectionDto}" method="POST">
            <h2>Kifizetések lekérése</h2>
            <div class="content-group">
                <select th:field="*{year}">
                    <option th:value="${payoutSelectionDto.year} -1"
                        th:text="${payoutSelectionDto.year} -1"></option>
                    <option th:value="*{year}" th:text="*{year}"></option>
                </select> <select th:field="*{month}">
                    <option th:value="'1'" th:text="Január"></option>
                    <option th:value="'2'" th:text="Február"></option>
                    <option th:value="'3'" th:text="Március"></option>
                    <option th:value="'4'" th:text="Április"></option>
                    <option th:value="'5'" th:text="Május"></option>
                    <option th:value="'6'" th:text="Június"></option>
                    <option th:value="'7'" th:text="Július"></option>
                    <option th:value="'8'" th:text="Augusztus"></option>
                    <option th:value="'9'" th:text="Szeptember"></option>
                    <option th:value="'10'" th:text="Október"></option>
                    <option th:value="'11'" th:text="November"></option>
                    <option th:value="'12'" th:text="December"></option>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="content-group">
                <select th:field="*{listingId}">
                    <option th:each="listingDto : ${listingListDto}" th:value="${listingDto.airbnbId}" th:text="${#strings.abbreviate(listingDto.airbnbLabel,30)}"></option>    
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="content-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Lekérés indítása</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the ListingListDtoService. It has a way of screening for duplicates, so unless this is not doing what I think it is doing, no duplicates should be there from the result of running this service.

```
@Service
public class ListingListDTOService {
    List<ListingDTO> listingDtoList;

    public ListingListDTOService() {
        this.listingDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<ListingDTO> getListingListDTO(List<Listing> listingList) {
        for(Listing listing : listingList) {
            ListingDTO listingDto = convertListingToListingDTO(listing);
            if(!listingDtoList.contains(listingDto)) {
                listingDtoList.add(listingDto);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("identical Dto found in list while adding Dtos.");
            }

        }
        return listingDtoList;
    }
    public ListingDTO convertListingToListingDTO(Listing listing) {
        ListingDTO listingDto = new ListingDTO();
        listingDto.setAirbnbId(listing.getAirbnbId());
        listingDto.setAirbnbLabel(listing.getAirbnbLabel());
        listingDto.setAirbnbPictureUrl(listing.getAirbnbPictureUrl());
        return listingDto ;
    }

}
```

Thanks to the coments from @Seth, this problem has been resolved.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see the code for ListingListDtoService, as you are seeing your problems in the result of this service, correct?

Comment: Thanks KevinB for the comment. I have added the ListingListDtoService.

Comment: If you don't have a good equals()/hashcode() method on ListingDTO, then your contains() call won't do what you want.

Comment: Thank you @Seth. I have implemented the equals()/hashcode() methods, and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just copying from the comments to answer this.

If you don't have a good equals()/hashcode() method on ListingDTO, then your contains() call won't do what you want.